# Active Directory: User must change password at Next login

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to change user password programmatically by using LDAP. User has flag "User Must Change Password at Next Logon" in the Active Directory. But I can't authenticate to Active Directory by this user. I used two LDAP auth types - simple and GSSAPI (Kerberos). Can somebody explain, how Windows itself change password when checked "User Must change password"? Kerberos falls on `AS_REQ-AS_RSP (AS)` step and return Error `STATUS_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE` while authentication.

Comment: AFAIK that's a custom AD feature that is supported only by Microsoft SSPI libraries. Standard GSSAPI libraries won't help. Welcome to WestMicrosoftWorld...

Comment: Did you try a PowerShell script with the AD client module?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Samson for your comments.

When user has checked "Must change password at next login", Windows first try to get ticket for SPN kadmin/changepw and after that use KPASSWD service (464 UPD/TCP) to change user password by using KPASSWD protocol (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3244). I tried to change password by using Windows for "Must change password" user and after that analyze package by Wireshark, all works in according to rfc3244. Also, I tried to use MIT KPASSWD tool, and password was changed like Windows.

Packages from client to Active Directory
[image]

Details of KPASSWD package
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, trying to reset a password from a python application when the user have an expired password (or the admin checked the "Reset PWD at next logon" checkbox. @AlbertAshrafzyanov refers to MIT's [kpasswd](http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/user/user_commands/kpasswd.html) tool available from Ubuntu package named "krb5-user". Not sure how to install it on other Linux distros. Not sure if this features can be implemented directly from code (without using cli tool)